# Papyrus - Regular expression error in constraint

Tags: regex, constraints, papyrus

The regular expression below validates dates in "dd/mm/yyyy", "dd.mm.yyyy" and "dd-mm-yyyy" formats and it works perfectly on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

**Regex:**

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

However, when I include it in a constraint in Papyrus it gives the following error:

[image]

In addition to the above error, I know that I must use the escape character in some places, but I am not able to make it work. Has anyone had this problem and managed to solve it?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try doubling backslashes and remove ``\``s before `/`s.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, thanks for your help. I tried but the same error appears, with a few more characters underlined by error: ^(?:(?:31(/|-|\.)( <= that  ?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$

Comment: Did you try `.matches("` with a double quote?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hello. Unfortunately not accepted. I even tested it together with Wiktor's answer above and nothing. Thank you anyway...